# Particular proof of the fundamental theorem of equivalence relations

Tags: proof-explanation, equivalence-relations

I have some trouble understanding the following proof. After doing some research, I realized that this is (probably) the Fundamental Theorem of equivalence relations. I didn't understand the proofs I found online and I struggled specifically with the following proof:

**Theorem**: Let $R$ be an equivalence relation on the set $X$. Then every element $a \in X$ belongs to exactly one equivalence class and for any two equivalence classes $A, A'$ we either have $A=A'$ or $A \cap A' = \emptyset$.

**Proof**: For a fixed $a \in X$ we define $A := \{x \in X : x \sim a\}$. We show that $A$ is an equivalence class that contains $a$. Because of $a \sim a$, we have $a \in A$ and therefore $A \neq \emptyset$. For $x,y \in A$, we have $x \sim a$ and $y \sim a$ and therfore also $x \sim y$.

If $x \in A, y \in X$ and $x \sim y$, then we have $x \sim a$ and $y \sim a$ and therefore $y \in A$. Now we have shown that $a$ is contained in at least one equivalence class[*].

Now we need to show that two equivalence classes $A$ and $A'$ are either the same or disjoint. Let $A \cap A' \neq \emptyset$ and $a \in A \cap A'$. If $x\in A$, then we have $x \sim a$ and because of $a \in A'$ we also have $x \in A'$. Therefore, we have $A \subset A'$. We can prove $A' \subset A$ analougsly. Therefore, $A = A'$.

[*] This is the step I am having trouble with. Why did we assume that $y \in X$ and not $y \in A$ as we have done before? First we let $x,y \in A$ to show that $x \sim y$ and then we set $y \in X$ to show that $y \in A$? Don't we use $x \sim y$ to show that point and $x \sim y$ dependes on $x,y \in A$? And why does it follow that $a$ is contained in at least one equivalence class?

Comment: I don't like this. A set defined as $A$ is **by definition** an equivalence class wrt to $\sim$ provided that $\sim$ denotes an equivalence relation. That is not something that has to be proved somehow. Unless some other definition of "equivalence class" is practicized, but I cannot think of any. Also nowhere in the "proof" I meet the terms "reflexive, symmetric, transitive".

Comment: If for every $a$ the set $[a]:=\{x\in X\mid x\sim a\}$ is by definition an equivalence class then on base of reflexivity we have $a\in[a]$ for every $a\in X$. This tells us immediately that every $a\in X$ is element of some equivalence class.

Comment: The terms reflexive, transitive, symmetric don't appear, but their use (reflexive and transitive at least ) is clear in the 3rd and 4th sentences of the first paragraph of the proof. (I think that symmetric is used in there too.) But I agree that the proof's not great. This appears to be a proof meant to convince people who already believe the statement, rather than to lead a new student through understanding of the material.

Comment: @drhab so you are saying that the statement "a is contained in at least one equivalence class" is by the definition of the equivalence class true and doesn't have to be shown? What about the other parts of the proof? I obviously don't like the proof either. However, I would still love to understand it :)

Comment: @Marwan I decided to give you an alternative. See my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\sim$ denote an equivalence relation on set $X$.

That means that the relation is reflexive, symmetric and transitive.

If we define for every $a\in X$ the set:$$[a]:=\{x\in X\mid  a\sim x\}$$ then the *reflexivity* of $\sim$ tells us immediately that $a\in[a]$.

*Transitivity* tells us that:$$c\in[a]\text{ and }x\in[c]\implies x\in[a]$$
or equivalently:$$c\in[a]\implies[c]\subseteq[a]\tag1$$

By *symmetry* we find:$$c\in[a]\iff a\sim c\iff c\sim a\iff a\in[c]$$This tells us that $(1)$ can be replaced by the stronger statement:$$c\in[a]\iff[c]=[a]\tag2$$

So if $[a]$ and $[b]$ have an element $c$ in common then $(2)$ tells us immediately that $[a]=[c]=[b]$.

This shows that for sets $[a]$ and $[b]$ there are only two options: they are disjoint or they coincide.

The sets of form $[a]$ are by definition the *equivalence classes* induced by $\sim$.

If $A\subseteq X$ is such an equivalence class then $A=[a]$ for every $a\in A$ and an element of $A$ is a so-called *representative* of the class.

As shown above these sets form a [partition](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_of_a_set) of $X$.

Comment: Your answer makes perfect sense, thanks. However, the proof I posted in my question is still not clear. Is the problem in the proof? It is in my textbook so I don't think that the Prof. made a mistake.

Comment: How exactly is an equivalence class **defined** in the proof? There they start with a **proof** that $A$ **is** an equivalence class, but that can only be done if there is some definition of "equivalence class". That is the main thing that bothers me in the proof.